# Как с наименьшими затратами получить конкретные данные из базы в php файле?

Tags: php

У меня есть база db.php

путь до файла

/var/www/user/data/www/site.org/bl-content/databases/plugins/test

```
<?php defined('BLUDIT') or die('Bludit CMS.'); ?>
{
"shortname": "Test",
"number": "2",
"enablePages": false,
"enableSites": true,
"enablePosts": true,
"position": 1,
"my_id": "100"
}
```

Как из нее получить данные поля my_id, если скрипт требующий эти данные находится в корне /var/www/user/data/www/site.org/script.php

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что путь в `$DB_PATH` правильный, но думаю вы сможете указать правильный:

```
$DB_PATH = '/bl-content/databases/plugins/test/db.php';

$FILE = file($DB_PATH);
unset($FILE[0]);
$FILE = json_decode(implode('', $FILE), TRUE);
var_dump($FILE['my_id']);
```